# Ag-Charts - All Font related options under the "Format" tab are disabled. Any ideas on how to enable them?

Tags: ag-grid, ag-charts

As described in the title, we have an AG-chart where all options work great except for the fact that any control related to Fonts under the format tab are disabled.

I am not seeing anything obvious that would control lead to the disabling of these controls.

[Chart Format menu] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/WF2n4.png)

N/A Nothing yet... Investigating.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.